# Incorporating variable into <Applet> tag for use in CMS (Joomla)

Tags: java, php, joomla

I want to link a chess viewer app (Java) to my database of games (MySQL) in the CMS my site uses (Joomla).
The chess viewer is called using an  tag in a standard Joomla document. One of the parameters is the file location of the chess file to be displayed.  I have a database containing a whole load of these pgn files, together with their location on the server, and I want the user to be able to scroll through the database, select the file they want, and then the document will call that file into the chess viewer.

I am OK writing the php to get the filename from the database - done that, but then how can I get the returned filename (currently in a php array variable) into my

[applet .....]

[PARAM name=PgnGameFile value=*returned PHP variable*]

Any suggestions gratefully received.

PS I'm no programmer - I learned Algol 66 many moons ago, and I can find my way around simple php at a pinch, but I've not programmed in earnest for over 25 years - systems managers have people for that and teachers give it to good 6th formers to do (that covers my working life) , so best to assume a newbie dunce :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably better off writing a Joomla component instead of using a content tag. You can use a component builder like https://www.component-creator.com to create the component. You would not need to really know any PHP to build what you are after.